# Corrupted transactions

Tags: transaction

I have a couple of transactions which are able to pass through IRI MessageQ to my ZeroMQ-client

This client causes exceptions on those transactions, apparently the Unix timestamp is wrong. I don't have more info in this, but I have export=true and will grep the transaction files for those transactions and then post them here.

They are tagged as SPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999

https://thetangle.org/transaction/BDQGFFNT9KMBLBHJOJEKUEENGYPI9DHGJOLUTWBVKOMDJKRPJIBPTFVXFPWDUSFVKYAAMSKIZOKMZ9999

https://thetangle.org/transaction/BDQGFFNT9KMBLBHJOJEKUEENGYPI9DHGJOLUTWBVKOMDJKRPJIBPTFVXFPWDUSFVKYAAMSKIZOKMZ9999

```
tx FTQIXOHFOCFOUITCYFNWPIMAJZWUMHLETXP9QPRREMJQWMUSTPU9XQTYJNDEXKCZVFCTUNWJ9HNN99999 BB9999999999999999999999999 seconds ago
tx C9RFRHEESDAKG9MIIJAGKWNSQ9DGRDAJLVUEYIULJSJCAHOUAIELGSRRBQMATEFARKFFFZYRQKTYA9999 QB9999999999999999999999999 a minute ago
tx ZJVJYORVOBADHKENIGAAUPUOUSOGLSSXYO9WCVPXSXDEENLSEEDBTDRFLTBZ9NACEGWBAHWVLTJDA9999 IBC9WONKYTONKYSPAM999999999 seconds ago
tx BDQGFFNT9KMBLBHJOJEKUEENGYPI9DHGJOLUTWBVKOMDJKRPJIBPTFVXFPWDUSFVKYAAMSKIZOKMZ9999 TPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zmq_reader.py", line 44, in <module>
    zmq_reader_handler.on_data(socket.recv(), storage)
  File "/home/iota/zmq_reader_handler.py", line 42, in on_data
    print bcolors.GREY + 'tx', data[1], data[4], bcolors.YELLOW + arrow.get(int(data[5])).humanize(), bcolors.END
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/api.py", line 23, in get
    return _factory.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/factory.py", line 144, in get
    return self.type.utcfromtimestamp(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/arrow.py", line 116, in utcfromtimestamp
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
ValueError: year is out of range

tx QNNOYDAAVDTTYJZYRTPRG9TYDVLONKHGJCMUTCJVNRVLSVLKXHTTWUWWIAEFGF9XXPVEQTTLZFMX99999 999999999999999999999999999 17 hours ago
tx ALYT9PJDBGQRBRVOPRSIQHQAKCHQQWAXRNJAS9CCKVEKZMFVKAHLRFJKXFKLWETMSCAESNTTIEJPZ9999 ED9999999999999999999999999 just now
   17 tx per 10 sec (1.7 tx/s)
```

Lot's of good transactions:

```
tx XMKAGCGLWDACIMDMDVCHUXOFNGNNQDTFPD9COUFWWFQXSMD9TLTLJNGEBLWPGSSBTXM9ROZRX9QBA9999 LB9999999999999999999999999 seconds ago
tx SLPDHLCOOQIZWBFUVLNXWWAHUVUAAALLTRDJQKZWQDYUHKDAGJQUJOOSVT9IO9RAFZTBHUFLWCHNA9999 999999999999999999999999999 an hour ago
tx 9FYISSTOOGPRVKFJLWRF9ZZQJHRLKDGXWZWJLVLPEBSTQHVCMNHLDWOAGNUKGVWUBFKACRPREFYCA9999 JZAFHLHZMNJQJGMTKVSRTHAPRJL a day ago
tx CPEOYUYRSQITTKUAOBAXJFCXMCOWB9RUIBNYW9YOWDDVRCTNYDYEOWCGQYNEDVHCKPAWUVTEIBVI99999 RZAFHLHZMNJQJGMTKVSRTHAPRJL a day ago
rstat --- toProcess = 0 , toBroadcast = 0 , toRequest = 419 , toReply = 0 , totalTransactions = 7076916
tx ZESBKYFGCPUAVUMXEIFIJ9MVFMFEAWTDWNLXSFLBCLCAHGXPBIPZBJMOUXHCMMXUUCHQUZ9NIESM99999 CPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zmq_reader.py", line 44, in <module>
    zmq_reader_handler.on_data(socket.recv(), storage)
  File "/home/iota/iota/zmq_reader_handler.py", line 42, in on_data
    print bcolors.GREY + 'tx', data[1], data[4], bcolors.YELLOW + arrow.get(int(data[5])).humanize(), bcolors.END
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/api.py", line 23, in get
    return _factory.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/factory.py", line 144, in get
    return self.type.utcfromtimestamp(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/arrow/arrow.py", line 116, in utcfromtimestamp
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
ValueError: year is out of range

tx FMXFVSCMFTDMCRMHBQZCXAPIMZVZJKHXFJPTZLKKVGAODIUVGTCKVLXJJZAUJVHRQSMZSWEUKDUP99999 999999999999999999999999999 a day ago
  110 tx per 60 sec (1.8 tx/s)
   13 tx per 10 sec (1.3 tx/s)
tx ZTOBOTYPOPUDYDRRWDZVMXFFYXJTQOAMYJWIUJIDWKZJDOSRKSRBESUATYGOPLIYHWUOYSIHHIKUA9999 ANDROID9WALLET9TRANSFER9999 seconds ago
tx ESMJ9JOPZGNYFXFDFUWHAFGVOTOSWTAMQUDGFQDEKXZFPF9BSGFKJZQQBVUSNQQENNQNUPWXVBIG99999 ANDROID9WALLET9TRANSFER9999 seconds ago
tx KFY9RLSU9PCHIXZEA9GMIJIKVSKCKMWDHJCUSSOGMCHK9PVHYIIEBDZZMEQJSMMYYLGIOHWLYFXJZ9999 ANDROID9WALLET9TRANSFER9999 seconds ago
```

Shouldn't these have gotten rejected in IRI already?

Here are more of these, all of them have the same tag, and only those cause an exception

```
tx ZFA9LHYTSNZQEIIIDHJDSJZHTD9PUKXMYCXTFTNDWGA9ZFQIUKSFRRTLEWGPMKDZJSNHH9KJTROLZ9999 RSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx EZBEQONXCTCLPY9SHAPYNXPJLDWACBFD9ACLSRLM9SNQLXFZCTYZER9UQGDTRIRONOPBXBKCWEJKZ9999 NUAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx FWPWWUOXVSZRQQPZHYTIWHGCUDOXXPMSFHYUSTVVUSSUEHGDBHMAPOEGKHBFTFGXMIGFZAQXWYWPA9999 ZQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TLCRW9ALSKQVERORHWPKZRUUIGQB9FWFTENGBLTCROHWOREVUKBINXJVDODBS9LRJYIJYWKEWFCXA9999 U9AMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx IGVODSUFWSDHOKOXUVZSIVVFAGWQX9KLVBKQBUYTCBTPVP9DHQMCMKNJ9JRVSDXBU9QYABIOAM9T99999 RQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx D9PVACDR9BGFGQEEXBSMPTCJWLYSGDRX9ZQEWENIIJHQBJWZSL9CGKZ9PCLVKAVAWKLLWZDGSC9SZ9999 ORAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx LJFICAWPRZL9TM9SHOUCLBPJLYLLUAP9SGDRRGWASKV9RRQYZKSMSMJFQZEXOZKRIZ9JVCFXQDYDZ9999 QYAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx VWYCAEOUJPLOACLCFFJQFHXFGGVHJEXYTIGHREZDIGKKHWYPTDXTCAYAFTIUDRPZCI9QMY9DRHDQ99999 DQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx NQRPYWUFPAQRNLTYUGSPREPV9DP9PIKKRMERGERWLDUTLOEZDVJLMYHVJYLWHGQPLHRIVSHVFZGRZ9999 X9AMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx SQHBYEWKKXKDUHDDPTNOAVTGLUOMRNEUICCVCJLVITUDQSUOTQESOYINJJVZYUJCFMIJZWWOVBJVZ9999 ISAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx VWAGTSHUKF9GROYYXFCAFEGJMQZQCKJWW9XINJEKYQSXYHQTHWY9NRMLQFEZYGQ9VCSREGXUERJSA9999 PQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx LRLFB9YIANC9KDJANANQBWBYAZKVSZLTZEWBFW9CJSOVNJWJ9CEF9YZYQFRGFYCPPHCNEMQROBP9A9999 WRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx BVBQ9IVUPGVTTEHYKIAVPCGUQAJVYKOYBE9ZHDSCA9TAS9TOVEYNJOHTH9NNEWFAYAFLIEMGHDKGZ9999 JUAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx UAGHNEFK9AKVGVE9APGJBNIXWTC9XTGFKQKQBAJTIQGYHQHFVIWHBNVKTAMLOMELRXGSMDPTPDRGA9999 CQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx IH9GXWCFGQNYLOWBIMKWZAZRDD99T9CMHZEITYJG9ANHNVOSPEANCZIJVQTVTQMCYSYYMTKTIMDGZ9999 OQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx SRTN9LMVDJWBLEDDDYOWYDGIHGCIVGJGICGDRPRVMLZHQZ99UQUTUPPDRYJRBTR99BASVSCTZBNCA9999 JPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx BZPYKVIXR9HICFVKQWQIWLPQUBYOGERIVXCCTVP9CIXHGEWIRVHEZEFFMWTGRXWMKVWFHHSFXJPUZ9999 DQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TEDEKALRAMUVQISVDMQDHAPYKKQBSCAMUTPDMWOUQJIMCYXEKNBLEZWWRHHRIQWLURPJXNWUBOTIA9999 KQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx HCYJSGRA9PTKWSCCOESLRM9USHLVCLBKX9FSITJBSZDUSIRQMTI9WRXSHTSEOWYWDPH9T9KJEVYH99999 JQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx GWUSKXSKDQJDNLDQWOUZDPJNZBOUGAUUCCBQLSGLSKSTVB9TXNOHXSSY9LUIXPKVSLRHLHERHQZFZ9999 9SAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx GKVILV9ZXNDDITSRKCCLDJMM9CAHUVIBNUNWWT9URAVDHBHQVDSUVTEZZSAJEQJFHJUDXHPRCFTG99999 YSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx ENCOKAHAZ9BDYFUJFFTCZWFARNBAEAIQJDXAJMQCAQMWIOIXRDLYESALMAUBRZOA9DHJJAIDCZFB99999 VUAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx BDQGFFNT9KMBLBHJOJEKUEENGYPI9DHGJOLUTWBVKOMDJKRPJIBPTFVXFPWDUSFVKYAAMSKIZOKMZ9999 TPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx ZESBKYFGCPUAVUMXEIFIJ9MVFMFEAWTDWNLXSFLBCLCAHGXPBIPZBJMOUXHCMMXUUCHQUZ9NIESM99999 CPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx IJZAZGKTCZNIBMAUJQJWCHCIISFQKR9L9TSORAKVYKUZYEDWSNFKMHEDDILDUCEAJOJHD9VHWNWG99999 OQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx XCLNTANDNCVTUEKFAZWIRQOHYJXIVEWABUEED9XJIFY9JUHSEVJ9KMRF9ASZ9KYQRQWQAFH9PMGLZ9999 FYAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TGFNHJLWRVQIEUSSFOCCRMJFKJFXEHQHMVEFSSADUNBSFTPOZJTHJGFLNMZIWBWYBATIKNNZAOAIZ9999 DSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx F9R9YMASCQHIBCBKLQJTRQJXZRQZZZQJEYW9FALNHRCMJTULM9HRIXYOOVQMUEJWYVCMJNUFAVOR99999 9TAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TPIUMEKFKXBBMUJYZLNUJUAYRAJMEWTRFGNNSFYJKX9BZIHKQQHSGLNTNQIOYODCMZIVDNXEDJSV99999 XPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx AUQMRCEMBEDWJOKWARYCRXIUMMHIE9RJGW9QKICX9FHHDHWCFFPMCJMTLSIIHIICUPTUJIEGEWWTA9999 MEAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TGSSCMQKUPCTSLDXJTHEQGGLBUWYOSLUJGUWWKIKSYUYLRQDP9PIKPWBXEAKEZFPPTEKTYAFFTWFA9999 OLAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx OFZLUSUSBDGFAKMVNHV9NSHOGRJOBIHSZJDTYZQLL9CKBCEIRQWGYTBTQRUFQKOWVZEBWYOMGOBR99999 PTAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx MO99XGCVLLEU9PAWKXPCYPRDASIDOG9VYFCHPWEQJ9KYRSWMORDGOUPSWRFJLSVYCEULTPKFKXEKZ9999 RVAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx PRKLUARLN9FDHSWV9RXXOFUJNNQBKDMJES9JPSYSZGBKUNJLFAUHH9DJXYYTSSYYMUWSRXWZTKYXA9999 DVAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx 9HFAOUN9LNSSOPFBEGSPXNLWHHSMFXJIGFWUHNRWENAQGLLWEUWEGEGNSCMFOCSEZAIINBUVQIYBZ9999 NDAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx JANJLQAXQKXVJS9TRWHRTDUDJDANJBTCWBBXNFWMABNODAHOTEKPEJJGBURPYXPVHHZXFRLXVJXQA9999 CRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx XXUSGXLWRPMUQEBD9TBMSFRQKDQXCDBYGFVGLOSOVBQVXSPPIRNCRVWPRDKWBFVDNICUDGHPOOHNZ9999 LSBMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx PEZ9EHD9BPTOSFSXRNCMNYKIVMIC9SREJFMNUYKQHTKTHJBVMYJYDU9VJ9GJU9SDOHXDBKLBFWTNA9999 XSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx 9ABNEAQUTDMWHTIJDDD9FVERONPHAPCCURFAYJOWKTW99ZCJYBDKQOQXDZRDLATWHYZLGDDE9NANZ9999 VRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx XIWXZOPMLAOITRZXBTEKQHPZSWBIUYELHIETIK9WMVJWIJSERWJNWSHCEZHXJYSBP9IHRNUHUOKA99999 9PAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx FCLKXRSNXDEVWCJOMEWHRKOOEMZ9F9TNRCUVTAAAEJOJTCHZQZJNINOQNWZCKLDQMTGOL9OSBDRCZ9999 WYAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx ODJK9FUFXFRTW9CMNFILMTRELRXNBBNSMZKU9WJHMTCIFQDUCXBFLPIFALWIK9SHRZQEYMRENNMQZ9999 DTAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx SXBOEWYNWHZDPDSFQOLZOA9HTWFML9YBSGIBRHQSUENYYLBZVKFKVNJTYYALRYNCQHNJWVUENNDM99999 QRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx CEQYJQGJHEK9SKSLOUE9WDNYTSSNUPHREVLLYFSMSBPBNOGQUYPIBANEXNFY9D9RIAOCWHVP9FRRA9999 9UAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx MVHENBFJWUCBPQJQVNNABQCCWZBRGSLIXNFBROEEOTNWWSLJESDJ9HFIRTNMYORMSMEVQCWUCIVDA9999 JPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx SRLGDFGAKSCOSO9XVATORZZNIEYKNLHMKKTEFKLYWCK9KSGIWCXAZSTGOEDQHMXZUKEWSUIQJENNA9999 LSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx AYIDSHOFHPUGBTBPDVRR9PUEXJCSFKKVVPVXHGGECCENMZVZEVWIIBXZVHGYNPMKVQC9UBX9GOWEA9999 EWAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx ZDUOSUJDMDLEQGGRYCGVGZTHECDDKXIEQAWSLWPPKWYIDIKFHBOQJFVWFNMUQOJTMEWCMQOXCYSMA9999 NQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx YD9JASJJQN9DARCFRGTDJGKIGVMSSMJJHDCUOUJLWEHLJBJFJODZLPFKUFPLBDUHISADTDLOSXUZZ9999 APAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx 9GBFUQATJLTTVPELBXIISIJ9Z9IBVBFDSDFGPNHR9BIWZZXQEJJREMITCPUSNCFPEHKMEBPQZFOHA9999 ATAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx L9ORAPKTYRRFUKWLAPIUWYDDHRNBGLZPECTPXPWYNYKJGJ99K9NYGJVQTBKKVBEGNQTVXEUMXVSU99999 IVAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx OFYESJOWL9NAECDRHXXNXXNZPUYONDFJKDQMWFZBMHXNEHCM9A9L9RPBZBZTHGFLXKJRLHFOI9LWZ9999 T9AMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx KUXAAYXMTKOPEWMZEEB9OGORWYMWKVWBKTG9YIBG9ANPHHZFSMFJEXRWCLAZMUMXHKMOQFB9WSJW99999 FPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx PDBFPTKVADSBRZRCZJESZPTG9URPFXWUKWYXK9TWUXLQRFPFCFNZWEYEEXQJDDEWLWUTWXPRETPIA9999 ERAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx KWHFUCCKFAWPPIJYLTAGNVJYTGUAJ9GNF9CRWJSZ9T9DBGJLZAWPPWIGZOGRLARRKSYIDFFIMITWA9999 YPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx YIDGWHGZEXRZJXFSTNQRSLEPOGSS9ZTYCPKMIAGQWDSOMRNH9HJGKPRLOUYQFVFHKFQXHEJPXMJSZ9999 LFAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx KTPPMSXZUJTSGBFYLDMZGZVSLYERQPHU9GSCOBTBYISVWYDWDWYANOGTDIYOTXGXATEGVHIOTFWQA9999 MSAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx QFX9EGRREQERFFATXUBKBHGBBNBQXLLPPRFEAAICFPDVMMPRQCOACQVMOJO9HGSRSAOCUBLLOFAD99999 NCAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx VHRDZLIJCVNNMVNWLKUIDMHNAUAKTSHJYMXTVHHJZTDIUIELPQLOPQDOWTXCMMYVXJMBZZGKJGZHA9999 SRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx TKOICFOJBH9WZALXFOUAU9HABOAWCEFBQDGLIEYBMCETMALDWAFNMQBWKFHKWYCDBCBCRBQKCUKVZ9999 SZAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx LWMNLCXZRSMQMHNTXXOPYZCJDQSDQMOWIUSQIFYNWPRIAXUTFXYZ9HWKVGVAZGWGGJUTWHXWYSMIZ9999 OTAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx QWEQFBNHEEZCVOUT9UARNFSCZJRNIICXSTXXQVCDVOKKJSPCPAIXVPGJQOLPUBLY9BANGMNIYY9VZ9999 USAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx DIQLNLOGVL9ZZCNBLBI9TJCRFIGWDTDLZISKRDHCLWNIZOMZHHBSNCSUNBWLKVXUKS9VKVRJQYOCA9999 WPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx RMWBDMW9HHHZQUCECJHGBZURKSIWJPRLOSHCBBZVGRTLCIFBDPFWO9OYFJOSBAQITCRLXQSJUFJR99999 TRAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx QEQTCPDKTZGFEBKEOXTPSIWCZRSYORGZROJUVXOHWLQVOTFTTVJT9AVAKUSTWWELYZLQUGDR9FVQ99999 QQAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx FNOJTVQXQWRCNBTHLUIZXYPQDUWGFRE9VGQOSNVPGUCIUSROUHTFN9ULLOZMIYSAUQUZUHTPPMCO99999 GPAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
tx DHR9JRTIWBHXTACWMCAOKPHQDBBCZJXTCCWDOTLG9PRNHOMMWNBPCTBKKCQFXYQYDGUREKMJJVCHZ9999 CXAMTRIUMPHISNEAR9999999999 exception in zmq_reader_handler.on_data(...)
```

Comment: The time is set here https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/3aebf94425509798d046ac5b47302817ab65bb4d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L385 and here https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/ad3db864b998358f3756d643178822ea9cf7105d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/service/API.java#L552 not sure why it’s devided by 1000 once. Bug? Since the time comes from the iri itself I think this is where to look for the problem?

Comment: I find it suspicious that only tx's with that tag were causing the problem.

Comment: Hm, do you parse the tag as time by any chance? What code is responsible for parsing the time? FYI the ZMQ message is constructed here https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/f021610fc871efd20325ac8fd602b7a408b985d7/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/storage/ZmqPublishProvider.java#L56-L70

Comment: `arrow.get(int(data[5]))` where `data[5]` is the result of `data = line.split()` which maps to IRI code `sb.append(String.valueOf(transactionViewModel.getTimestamp()));`

Comment: BTW, that time doesn't come from IRI itself, it is stored in the transaction.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was referring to the `ArrivalTime`, you were talking about the `transactionViewModel.getTimestamp`

Comment: The odd thing is that the timestamp shows no issue inside of rocksdb. Maybe it was related to the ZeroMQ client, but what confuses me is the fact that only tx's with that tag caused the issue.